# Setting sampling rate of serial.readline()

Tags: python, serial-port

How can I execute ser.readline() at a controlled rate, say every 0.002 seconds? The following code below in Python returns a list of varying sizes after every run, meaning the sampling rate varies every time. I was wondering if there was a controlled way of reading from the serial port given a desired sampling rate of 500 scans/second:

```
import numpy as np
from time import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200, timeout=1)
ser.flushInput()

digital_data = np.array([])

# Set the end time 60 seconds from start
te = time() + 60

# While loop runs for 60 seconds
while time() <= te:
    digital_data = append(digital_data, ser.readline().decode('utf-8'))

print(len(digital_data)) # Varies in size for each run
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be exact depending on the OS you're running...

```
import numpy as np
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200, timeout=1)
ser.flushInput()

digital_data = np.array([])

# Set the end time 60 seconds from start
te = time.time() + 60

delay = 0.002

while time.time() <= te:
    start = time.time()
    digital_data = append(digital_data, ser.readline().decode('utf-8'))
    duration = time.time() - start
    if duration < delay:
        time.sleep(delay - duration)

print(len(digital_data)) # Varies in size for each run
```

Comment: This does not return consistent sizes of the list. Running for 60 seconds the first time, I got a list size of 3800, then the second time I got 3770. I am running on Windows

Comment: In the first line I wrote `this may not be exact depending on your os`. Unless you're running a RTOS you cannot guarantee that rate of execution.

Comment: If consistent size is the goal, why not disregard time and simply return once there are a certain amount of characters ingested?

Comment: I'm reading crucial data from an Arduino board that must be timestamped

Comment: It sounds like you're using you're utilizing the computer as a DAQ. Ideally your data should be timestamped on the arduino side via a RTC, that would eliminate the issue you're experiencing. A standard OS cannot guarantee sub millisecond accuracy.